# Match string pattern in column names via loop and append as new column to dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame with column names as such:

```
abc_alpha = c(1,2,3,4)
abc_beta = c(5,6,7,8)
abc_char = c(9,10,11,12)
xyz_alpha = c(4,3,2,1)
xyz_beta = c(8,7,6,5)
xyz_char = c(12,11,10,9)
```

and my dataframe (df):

```
abc_alpha  abc_beta  abc_char  xyz_alpha  xyz_beta  xyz_char
   1          5         9         4          8         12
   2          6         10        3          7         11
   3          7         11        2          6         10
   4          8         12        1          5         9
```

I would like to loop through the columns and match the columns that have the same end of the strings (after the underscore), take the average of two matching columns and append it to the end of the data frame as a new variable (col name for the new variable will be the matched string after the underscore). I'd like to use a loop instead of hard-coding the column names as the real dataset has way too many columns.

Expected output will be:

```
abc_alpha abc_beta abc_char xyz_alpha xyz_beta xyz_char alpha beta char
   1         5        9        4         8       12      2.5  6.5  10.5
   2         6        10       3         7       11      2.5  6.5  10.5
   3         7        11       2         6       10      2.5  6.5  10.5
   4         8        12       1         5       9       2.5  6.5  10.5
```

I've written the first part of the loop function, but can't seem to finish by appending the new columns to the dataframe:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {

  x <- (strsplit(names(df)[i], split = '_', fixed = T))[[1]][2]
```

I've browsed through possibly similar questions, but as I'm new to R, alot of answers that suggest using the Apply family have gotten me confused and I've been unable to adapt those solutions to my situation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the data by a grouping variable created by removing the substring and get the `rowMeans`

```
cbind(df, sapply(split.default(df, sub(".*_", "", names(df))), rowMeans))
#abc_alpha abc_beta abc_char xyz_alpha xyz_beta xyz_char alpha beta char
#1         1        5        9         4        8       12   2.5  6.5 10.5
#2         2        6       10         3        7       11   2.5  6.5 10.5
#3         3        7       11         2        6       10   2.5  6.5 10.5
#4         4        8       12         1        5        9   2.5  6.5 10.5
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, `gather` the columns into 'long' format, then `separate` the 'key' column into two colums by the separator `_`, `summarise` to get the `mean` after grouping by the row names and the 'key2', `spread` to 'wide' and bind with the original dataset using `bind_cols'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% # create a rowname column
  gather(key, val, -rn) %>% # convert to long format
  separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2')) %>% # split column into two
  group_by(rn, key2) %>% # grouping with columns
  summarise(val = mean(val)) %>% # get the mean 
  spread(key2, val) %>% # convert to wide format
  ungroup %>% # remove the groups
  select(-rn) %>% # select only columns of interest
  bind_cols(df, .) # bind with the original dataset
# abc_alpha abc_beta abc_char xyz_alpha xyz_beta xyz_char alpha beta char
#1         1        5        9         4        8       12   2.5  6.5 10.5
#2         2        6       10         3        7       11   2.5  6.5 10.5
#3         3        7       11         2        6       10   2.5  6.5 10.5
#4         4        8       12         1        5        9   2.5  6.5 10.5
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(abc_alpha, abc_beta, abc_char, xyz_alpha, xyz_beta, xyz_char)
```